# How can I package my python module and its dependencies such as Numpy/Scipy into one file like dll for C# calls?

Tags: c#, python, .net, pyinstaller, python.net

In my project, some of the algorithms are implemented in python as Modules for calling  and libraries such as Numpy/Scipy are used . Now I need to embed these Modules into my UI(implemented by C# and run in Windows 7). There are two reasons I need to package my python modules into a file like DLL(I don't want to package as an .exe because it is not friendly to embed). The first reason is for easily calling, and the second reason is to protect my algorithm source code.  Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I solve my problem by using nuitka. It compile my module into .pyd file, and I can import the module using pythonnet by adding reference Python.Runtime.dll.
My compile command is:`nuitka --module  --nofreeze-stdlib --recurse-all --recurse-not-to=numpy --recurse-not-to=sklearn --recurse-not-to=pywt --recurse-not-to=matplotlib --recurse-not-to=matplotlib.pyplot --recurse-not-to=scipy.io myfile.py`
and my C# code is:

```
PythonEngine.Initialize();
IntPtr pythonLock = PythonEngine.AcquireLock();
PythonEngine.RunSimpleString("import sys\n");
PythonEngine.RunSimpleString("sys.path.append('C:\\path\\to\\pyd')\n");
PyObject pModule = PythonEngine.ImportModule("modulename");
pModule.InvokeMethod("funcitonname", para1, para2);
```

Comment: Wow! This is great, pyinstaller developers just informed me today that to compile pyd nuitka or cython have to be used.

Comment: perhaps you could post a gist or github project with a minimal example for nuitka that I can share with pythonnet community?

Answer (score 0):

Try pythonnet to embed CPython in .NET:

[python4.net](http://www.python4.net)

Comment: I have two requirements. The first requirement is that I need to package my python source code in a form that is not easily cracked. The other requirement is that I need to integrate the generated package into my C # code. Pythonnet can meet my second requirement but how about my first requirement?

Comment: just use pyinstaller for packaging your code:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1801

Comment: yeah, may be it works, but finally I solve my problem by using nuitka.